# Fix Module Errors in Android Studio: Missing settings.gradle and project dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, module

I have a project that has module dependencies.
I cannot compile it due to Module errors.

[image]

[image]

There is no module in the edit config.
There isn't also a settings.gradle file
How can I import a module dependency by only referring to its path?